# Are ex-CP-9 members present in CP-0?

Tags: one-piece

In the chapter 801 of *One Piece*, characters resembling Rob Lucci and Spandam were shown.

Are the former CP-9 members really in CP-0?

Answer (score 4):

There is no evidence on what happened, but yes, they are. It's actually pretty clear if you see the chapter:

> [image]

And also this is from the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/):

> After the timeskip, Lucci reappeared as a member of CP-0. Lucci went to Dressrosa to recover evidence of the Donquixote Pirates smuggling operation only to find that they were already taken. Lucci suspected that the revolutionaries were responsible.