# Who and what are the members of CP 0?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece during the dressrosa arc, it is shown that members of the world government's CP 0 were present on the island.

What exactly is CP 0? 
Does this mean there is a CP 1 - 8 as well?

And if they were stronger than CP 9, how did some of them end up turning into toys?

I am current on the anime and manga and don't mind spoilers. I'm just confused about this.

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26137/6166

Comment: Ontopic: there should be CP0 to CP9, yet this makes it much more confusing to see the members of CP9 (Spandam and Lucci) be promoted all the way to CP0 in just 2 years. So either CP members get fired often, or they really do die very often...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Cipher_Pol):

> So far, the CP agencies seen on the Grand Line are CP5, CP6, CP7, CP9 and CP-0.
>
> There are eight official Cipher Pols that are numbered from CP1 to CP8 with two unofficial units, which are named CP9 and CP-0 . Cipher Pol No. 9 has the license to kill any citizen that does not cooperate with the World Government or acts in contrary to its interests. Because such a radical method of applying justice by the World Government should not be common knowledge, this group is a top secret organization. CP-0 is apparently more powerful than the CP9 as they are called the world's strongest intelligence.

-CP-0, more properly known as Cipher Pol Aigis Zero is the **strongest intelligence organization** among Cipher Pol, according to Nico Robin.

-None of the CP-0 members were turned into toys. Although, Doflamingo does have control over them.

> Doflamingo revealed to Law that he was **granted authority to command CP-0 because he holds secret information about Mariejois' 'national treasure'**, which will shake the world if its existence is revealed to the public.

You can read about them in detail [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/CP-0)

Comment: So Lucci is a part of CP 0 officially now. That will make for an epic rematch if they fight later on. One last follow up, I haven't noticed anything since Dressrosa but has CP 0 made any moves or revealed where they are going to be next?

Comment: If I remember correctly, nothing of the sort is shown. We only see Rob Lucci and Spandem's glimpse in Chapter 801.. Nothing more. Although yeah, I can't wait for an epic fight scene later, if there will be any. For me, Luffy vs Lucci was the best fight in One Piece :D